# very simple ajax request returns [object Object]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is the javascript part of the code;

```
$.ajax
({
  type: 'POST',
  url: location.href,
  data: {
  'uploaded_data' : 'uploaded_data',
  },
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function(message) {},
  complete: function(message) 
  {
     alert(message);
  }
});
```

And here is the php part;

```
if(isset($_POST["uploaded_data"]))
{
    $text="test text";
    echo $text;
    exit();
}
```

For some reason alert message shows [object Object] message instead of "test text".
And the weird thing is if I try it like this;

```
alert(JSON.stringify(message));
```

it alerts this message;

```
{"readyState":"4", "responseText":"test text","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one `message.responseText`

```
$.ajax
({
  type: 'POST',
  url: location.href,
  data: {
  'uploaded_data' : 'uploaded_data',
  },
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function(message) {},
  complete: function(message) 
  {
     alert(message.responseText);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your complete function to this to get the message:

```
complete: function(data) {
    alert(data.responseText)
}
```